# Wine Installation

Tags: 14.04, wine

I tried to install `wine` on my `Ubuntu 14.04` by using following commands,

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

and i get following:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/ trusty/universe winetricks all 0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2 [131 kB]
Err ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/ trusty/universe winetricks all 0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2
  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/pool/universe/w/winetricks/winetricks_0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2_all.deb  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

And i also tried with PPA as follows,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

But the result is same. How can i fix it ?.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using helps to ensure you have the latest WINE, which I will agree is supposed to be the best.  However among my ubuntu geek friends, I'm the most successful with WINE and that's not how I installed it.

I would advise you to use the version of WINE available from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Please try using [this link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/wine1.4/) and clicking on the orange button near the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest wine, you should add the wine ppa in your software sources list. In the terminal type the following commands:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
You can now install wine using the command `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`
Good luck with the install :)